# How to use go to build windows dll files on mac

Tags: go

How to use go to build windows dll files on mac
go version go1.21.5 darwin/arm64

example.go

```
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

//export SayHello
func SayHello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello from Go DLL!")
}

func main() {}
```

GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -o example.dll -buildmode=c-shared example.go

go: no Go source files

Comment: I doubt you can

Comment: Google "golang cross compile dll". This has been asked many times. Building a shared library is roughly equivalent to building a CGO, rather than statically linked, application. It requires a compiler tool chain, specifically a linker, that can generate the desired shared library. The macOS linker has no ability to produce a Windows DLL, AFAIK.

Comment: Also, while I appreciate the ability of the Go toolchain to produce statically compiled executables for other platforms I am also perplexed why people expect Go to handle dynamic linking on a foreign platform. This type of question always implies the person asking the question has no idea how compilation of source code is done. Consider whether you can even build an executable for a different platform in a different language.